# UILabel text always has a line break

Tags: ios

Screenshot of the issue:

[image]

```
self.label.text = @"回复111111111111111111111111111111111111111";
```

I wrote the code to set the text of label, but the label always has a line break right after the "回复". Can someone help me to get this text to display all in one line?

Comment: The `111111111111111111111111111111111111111` is count as 1 word, so it will make line break to show the word correctly, if you dont want, set a constraint to the label's height then it will become `11111111111...`

Comment: or you can change the line break mode to break character

Comment: @JsonKit Try my answer.

Comment: I have tried to set lineBreakMode,it can help,but I want the label to adapt to text height,after setting lineBreakMode,the label height is not correct@Surely

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sizeToFit` property of a UILabel to adjust the height as per the text. Once you set the text, you can simply call:

```
[yourLabel sizeToFit];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set UILabel like this :

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this code will adjust your font size according to your label width.

```
 label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```